# how to change a value of element on kustomize.yaml using github actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions, kustomize

if i having this kustomize.yaml file :

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

patches:
- patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /spec/rules/0/host
      value: the.new.domain.com
  target:
    kind: Ingress
    name: the_name_of_ingress
```

and i want to replace this value:`the.new.domain.com` with a new domain name using kustomize command with github actions like this : `kustomize edit set`
any idea how to make it ? even if u have another idea can letting me implement it inside the github actions its ok
tnx anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of some yaml processor like `yq` for this.

Example:

```
yq -i '.patches[0].patch = "- op: replace
 path: /spec/rules/0/host
 value: chetantalwar.com"' tes.yaml
```

I used this using CLI and it updated the file, and similarly you can put it in Github Action as well like give below.

```
  - name: Set foobar to cool
    uses: mikefarah/yq@master
    with:
      cmd: yq -i '.patches[0].patch = "Your Value"' 'kustomize.yml'
```

Links:

- [YQ](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)
- [YQ Github Action](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/github-action)

There is one more option which you can try is, templating your `kustomize.yaml` and in Github Action you can update the respective value using `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same usecase as @stack-acc and heavily inspired by response from @Chetan, found this

- kustomization.yaml

```
patches:
  - patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: "/metadata/name"
        value: proc-cls-s2e2-tcp
```

- `yq` command to replace just the value

```
yq -i '.patches.[0].patch |= sub("value: .*?$", "value: publ-cls-s2e2-udp")' kustomization.yaml
```

Don't have to repeat whole `op: replace` section in the script and just replace the value.

Answer (score 0):

I used this: https://github.com/fjogeleit/yaml-update-action

It lets you replace a value in a yaml and it can commit the changes back (or not, there's a bunch of options):

```yaml
name: 'workflow'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  update-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Update kustomize.yaml
        uses: fjogeleit/yaml-update-action@main
        with:
          valueFile: 'kustomize.yaml'
          propertyPath: 'patches.0.patch'
          value: 'some value here'
          commitChange: false
```